# Expected a valid update modifier using $addToSet MongoDb Nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I need to add a ref in my array using $addToSet.

It's my schema

```
  @Allow()  
  @ApiProperty(GatewaySchemaSwagger.API_PROP_ADMIN_ID)
  @Prop({required: true, type: [MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId] , ref: 'User' })
  admin: [User];
```

it's my collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("63c022bfd2d744ebaffe3412"),
"buttons" : [],
"admin" : [ 
    ObjectId("636bc633ccc1e71aa32ad831")
],
"user" : ObjectId("636bc633ccc1e71aa32ad831"),
"channelId" : "1",    
}
```

It's my update

```
let findUser = await this.usersService.findByEmail(data.email);
await this.GatewayModel.findOneAndUpdate({ admin: userId, channelId: channelId }, { $addtoSet: { "admin": [findUser._id]  } })
```

My error is:

> Unknown modifier: $addtoSet. Expected a valid update modifier or
> pipeline-style update specified as an array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a single item, use `$addtoSet` **without** the `[]` around the `findUser._id`

```
await this.GatewayModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { admin: userId, channelId: channelId },
  { $addtoSet: { "admin": findUser._id  } }
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wi8XGng7Fg5)

If you want to add an **array** of `MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId`, one option is to use update with pipeline with `$setUnion`:

```
await this.GatewayModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { admin: userId, channelId: channelId },
  [{$set: {admin: {$setUnion: ["$admin", [findUser._id]]}}}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rUgec428iBU)

- I think your schema should be: `@Prop({required: true, type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })`, since you already have `[]` around your `User`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, I have the same problem without []. `$addtoSet. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array` I need to use $addToSet to avoind the duplicate

Comment: Try your query directly on the db (robo 3T / studio 3T / compass) or try to create it on the playground to better understand the problem

Comment: your script is correct and what I did but without result, maybe the problem is on Schema, I don't understand

Comment: I think your schema should be: `@Prop({required: true, type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })`, since you already have `[]` around your `User`

Comment: I have the same problem, without [] or other "combinations"

Answer (score 0):

How I modified and it works now.

Schema:

```
  @Allow()  
  @ApiProperty(GatewaySchemaSwagger.API_PROP_ADMIN_ID)
  @Prop({required: true, type: [MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId] , ref: 'User' })
  admin: User[];
```